# Can't add to instance's hash (ruby)

Tags: ruby, hash

I am having trouble using `#buy_fish` to add to the instance's `#pets` hash. It successfully returns what is being added to the hash, but the hash doesn't change.

**Owner Class**

```
class Owner
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    pets
  end

  def pets
    @pets = {cats: [], dogs: [], fishes: []}
  end

  def buy_fish(name)
    self.pets[:fishes] << Fish.new(name)
  end
end
```

**Fish Class**

```
class Fish
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

Comment: Each call to `pets` assigns a new hash to `@pets`. Either move the assignment into `initialize` or use `@pets ||= { ... }`.

Comment: Also, I believe you want to do `self.pets[:fishes].push(Fish.new(name))`.  Otherwise, you're just setting the key to the single `Fish` instance every time.

Comment: Thank you Stefan. That worked. I hadn't learned ||= yet. Is there another way to do this? I feel like this is a cheat way out because I wrote bad code?

Also, John, I just noticed that when fixing the code up. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Matt's solution works.

I'll just add that I see no reason why `pets`' evaluation should be lazy here. Hence you can just inline it in the constructor and add a reader:

```
class Owner
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_reader :pets

  def initialize(name)
    @pets = {cats: [], dogs: [], fishes: []}
  end

  def buy_fish(name)
    @pets[:fishes] << Fish.new(name)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As Stefan pointed out, each call to `pets` asssigns a new hash to `@pets`. Adding `||=` in the pets method fixed this.

**Code**

```
def pets
  @pets ||= {cats: [], dogs: [], fishes: []}
end
```

Comment: That's not a "cheat way". In fact, it's a very common ruby idiom, called "memoization".